# Gnuplot polar grid without radial lines

Tags: gnuplot

Enabling Gnuplot's polar grid, using

```
set grid polar
```

creates a grid consisting of circles with radial spokes. I only want the circles. I can adjust the angle spacing between the radial spokes using

```
set grid polar <angle spacing>
```

but I have not found a way of removing the spokes completely. Instead of using a polar grid, should I create circles by either plotting an appropriate function or using `set object 1 circle ...` to achieve the effect that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you cannot remove the spokes completely. If you want to keep the raxis, you can set the polar grid to `360` or `2*pi`, depending on the angle
unit you use:

```
set polar
set angles radians
set grid polar 2*pi
set size square
plot t
```

[image]

Otherwise, yes, you must use `set object`, I couldn't find another way. But you can iterate this action to have it automated:

```
 set for [i=1:5] object i circle at 0,0 radius i*0.2 fillstyle border lt 0
```

or similar.

Comment: This is a way of avoiding intermediary circles, but the circles are what I want to keep - it is the radial lines (every 30 degrees by default, as you have here) that I wish to remove.